# AspNetCore custom TagHelpers not displaying

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I am running a AspNetCore application and trying to create a custom TagHelper, its just not rendering. I have read quite a few articles and i think i have everything i need.

***project.json***

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.1.3",
```

***_ViewImport.cshtml***

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

***ReverseTextDivTagHelper.cs***

The below code i got from an example i was trying

```
[HtmlTargetElement("tag-name")]
    public class ReverseTextDivTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        private string _divData = string.Empty;
        public string DivData
        {
            get
            {
                char[] reversedData = _divData.ToCharArray();
                Array.Reverse(reversedData);
                String sDataReversed = new String(reversedData);
                return AllCaps ? sDataReversed.ToUpper() : sDataReversed;
            }
            set { _divData = value; }
        }

        public bool AllCaps { get; set; }

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            output.TagName = "div";
            output.Content.SetContent(DivData);
        }
    }
```

And then in a partial view i am calling it like this

```
<reverse-text-div all-caps="true" div-data="Jacques"></reverse-text-div>
```

Comment: Can you please share entire content of `_ViewImports.cshtml`? Have you added ASP.NET Core web app namespace `@addTagHelper "*, AspNetCoreWebApp1"`?

Comment: Yes i have added it

Comment: Add HtmlAttributeName for your properties e.g. `[HtmlAttributeName("all-caps")]`

Comment: Sure will try it and let you know

Comment: its weird so i got it working by simplifying the name and removing the [HtmlTargetElement("tag-name")]. I am gona investigate some more and try and figure out what the actual cause it

Comment: `[HtmlTargetElement("tag-name")]` has to be `reverse-text-div`. It should be `[HtmlTargetElement("reverse-text-div")]`

Comment: Of of coarse i see how did i miss that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Point 1:** `[HtmlTargetElement("tag-name")]` has to be same as actual HTML tag i.e. `reverse-text-div`. It should be `[HtmlTargetElement("reverse-text-div")]`

**Point 2:** Apply `HtmlAttributeName` for your properties e.g. `[HtmlAttributeName("all-caps")]`